# Mr. Sloane's Tree

Tags: pattern, geometry, number-sequence

Mr. Sloane is a man that likes to draw trees with dots.

Give him two dots and he'll draw you one tree, but give him three and he'll draw you no tree.

How many trees can he draw with 6 dots? and with 11 dots?

Comment: Is [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3P6DWAwwViU) related?

Comment: @user477343 it isn't sorry!

Comment: @LuisSousa, which one of the answers provided by Gareth McCaughan is correct?

Comment: @El-Guest the second one, can you guess the inspiration for this (failed) puzzle?

Comment: Is there a special event/milestone happening with OEIS this week/today? I'm not at all familiar with what it might be, @LuisSousa unfortunately!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some possible answers. They all

> allow us to take "Mr Sloane" to be N J A Sloane, creator of the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences, "trees" to have its graph-theoretic sense, and "dots" to refer to the vertices of the trees.

First:

> Mr Sloane likes to draw *series-reduced planted trees*, sequence [A001678](http://oeis.org/A001678). In this case the numbers we need are 2 and 35 respectively.

Second and simpler:

> Mr Sloane likes to draw *series-reduced trees*, sequence [A000014](http://oeis.org/A000014). In this case the numbers we need are 2 and 14 respectively.

Third:

> Mr Sloane likes to draw *trimmed trees*, sequence [A002988](http://oeis.org/A002988). In this case the numbers we need are 2 and 39 respectively.

Unless the intended answer fits the given statement markedly better than all of these (or is one of these and fits markedly better than the other two for some reason), I think we need some further information if the puzzle is to have a definite correct answer.

Comment: You're right, with the information given all your answers fit in. Guess i should've formulated my question better, was thinking of providing a drawn tree initially but didn't want to give away too much information.

Comment: Your second answer is the correct one, i could edit my post to present a drawn tree from a _n_ number of nodes to guess the right sequence but i think it would be trivial now.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer is:

> 3 and 4.

My reasoning:

> 6 is evenly divided by two; this gives us **3** trees. 11 is divisible by two with a remainder of one; thus the math stops at 8 where the remainder (from 11) is three, thus only **4** trees.

Comment: Unless the "trees" and "dots" are an important part of this puzzle, we are just extrapolating a sequence that goes 1, 0, ... which is obviously ridiculous. So I think a viable answer needs to explain what's up with the trees and the dots.

Comment: This is a good point, and would make this a basic calculation which by the standards here is not a riddle. I based my answer on the `pattern` and `number-sequence` tags, which again point back to basic calculations. I'm not sure a direct correlation between the ***trees*** and ***dots*** can be deducted from the supplied information.

Comment: There's also the `geometry` tag. Again, if it's _not_ possible to figure out what's up with the trees and the dots then I think the puzzle is hopeless.

Comment: Perhaps a *node-like* structure being synonymous for ***trees*** and the ***dots*** being nodes; there's really no telling. I'm interested to find out what the answer is if mine is wrong.

Comment: Yes, I'm expecting the intended answer to be graph-theory-ish.

Comment: @PerpetualJ you can say the dots are **nodes** indeed.
It's better to draw like Mr. Sloane did.